# Always avoid in-out parameters in Java?

Tags: java, refactoring, parameter-passing

There's no doubt that in-out parameters leads to confused code since they may increase unexpected/unpredictabled side-effects.

So, many good programmers say :

> Avoid in-out parameters for changing mutable method parameters. Prefer to keep parameters unchanged.

For a perfectionist programmer who expects his code to be the most clean and understandable, does this "rule" must be applied in all case ?

For instance, suppose a basic method for adding elements to a simple list, there's two ways :

**First way (with in-out parameter):**

```
private void addElementsToExistingList(List<String> myList){
  myList.add("Foo");
  myList.add("Bar");
}
```

and the caller being :

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
//.......Several Instructions (or not) .....
addElementsToExistingList(myList);
```

**Second way without out parameter :**

```
private List<String> addElementsToExistingList(List<String> originalList){
      List<String> filledList = new ArrayList<String>(originalList); //add existing elements
      filledList.add("Foo");
      filledList.add("Bar");
      return filledList; 
    }
```

and the caller being :

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
//.......Several Instructions (or not) .....
myList.addAll(addElementsToExistingList(myList));
```

Pros of second way :

Parameter are not modified => no risk of unexpected side-effects for a new code reader.

Cons of second way :

Very verbose and very less readable ...

Of course, you would tell me that for a code as simple as this one, first way is really more convenient.

But, if we don't consider the difficulty of any concept/code, I juge the second way more logical and obvious for any readers (beginners or not).

**However, it violates the CQS principle that consider "command" methods having void return with potential (but allowed since it's the convention) side-effects and "query" methods having a return type and without side-effects.**

So, what should a motivate programmer adopt ? Mix of two accorging to the code case ? Or keep the "law" expecting to always avoid in-out parameters...

(Of course, method for adding Element is named for expliciting the example, and would be a bad name choice in real code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the law should be:

> Use what is more straight-forward, but *always*, **always** document the behavior of your methods extensively.

Your second example is a very nice case where without documentation you would have a guaranteed bug: the name of the method is `addElementsToExistingList`, but the method *does not add elements to the existing list - it creates a new one*. A counter-intuitive and misleading name, to say the least...

Comment: I very agree with you, but it represents the most popular style of methods that some (non-experimented always do) :) In fact, I read a lot of similar method with so bad names in place where I work in.

Answer (score 4):

There is a third way.  Wrap `List<String>` into a class that knows how to add elements to itself:

```
class ElementList {
   private List<String> = new ArrayList<String>();

   public void addElements(Element... elements);
}
```

I like this approach because it keeps the `List` implementation private.  You don't have to worry if someone passes an immutable list to your method or whether parameters are modified.  The code is simpler.  Long method names like `addElementsToExistingList` are code smells that an object is trying to do something another object should be doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should always document when mutating an object that is a parameter because otherwise this can have unintended side effects for the caller. In the first case I agree with the others that have commented that the method name is sufficient documentation.

In your second example, the elements that are already present in myList seem to be added twice. In fact you could entirely remove the parameter of the addElementsToExistingList method and rewrite it as:

```
private List<String> getElements() {
   List<String> filledList = new ArrayList<String>();
   filledList.add("Foo");
   filledList.add("Bar");
   return filledList; 
}

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
//.......Several Instructions (or not) .....
myList.addAll(getElements());
```

Note that this code is not equivalent to your second example because the elements are only added once, but I think this is actually what you intended. This is the style that I usually prefer. This code is easier to understand and more flexible than the first example without adding extra code (it may degrade performance very slightly but this usually isn't a concern). The client of getElements() can now also do other things with the element list besides adding it to an existing collection.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to change/mutate parameters as long as it's documented. And of course with a method name of "addElementsToExistingList", what else should someone expect? However, as someone previously pointed out, your second implementation returns a copy and doesn't modify the original, so the method name is now misleading. Your first way is a perfectly acceptable way of doing things. The only other additional improvements is to possibly add a true/false value to the return indicating true if only all the elements were added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example the name makes it clear - "addElementsToExistingList" to me seems pretty clearly to hint that you're going to .. er.. you know. But your concern would be justified with a less obvious name.

For example, in ruby this is commonly handled with naming conventions

`"a".upcase` => gives you the uppercase of the variable, leaves the original unchanged
`"a".upcase!` => alters the original variable

Comment: Except for a little detail: the *hint* is completely wrong in the second snippet, since the existing list is not modified :-)